# Java Sockets with Openshift

Tags: java, sockets, port, openshift, portforwarding

Through the use of many articles and Stack Overflow questions, I was finally able to successfully bind a Java Socket to a port (port 8000) on an Openshift website.

I know the binding was successful because no exceptions were thrown, and I was able to poll the Socket for its port number. I can also successfully connect to the socket from a client application I have, after using the rhc client tools to forward the ports.

The problem is, how do I connect to the server socket without port forwarding? I'm not able to connect to the server from any other computers, or from my own computer without port forwarding.

These are the things that I have tried so far:

- Connecting to "localhost" at port 8000, which works after port forwarding.
- Connecting to the website URL at port 8000, which always returns null.
- Connecting to the website IP at port 8000, which results in a "Connection refused: connect" error.

Client code:

```
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost"); 
        //Also tried '127.5.8.129' which openshift says is the website IP, and the website URL itself.
    Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 8000);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    out.println("Hello World");
    out.flush();

    System.out.println(in.readLine());

    socket.close();
```

EDIT: I can also bind the Server Socket to port 8443, but still can't access it remotely.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind to port 8080, and then access your application at it's public url on port 8000.  Check out this kb article for more information about how the ports work on OpenShift: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-

Comment: I think I had problems binding to port 8080 server-side, but I'll try again right now.

Comment: When I try to bind to 8080, it says the port is already in use

Comment: Then you already have something, like a java server maybe? running on port 8080.  Maybe you could give us more information about what cartridges you have running etc.

Comment: I currently have a single gear running, which is Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0). I thought this might be why 8080 is already in use, but I didn't know what I could do about it.

Comment: If you want to open a raw tcp socket on port 8080 you need to use a DIY gear instead.

Comment: Oh okay. What do I need to do to deploy my .war on a diy?

Comment: I tried out two DIYs, but both require that I have a java server-container on port 8080. How can I get around this?

Comment: I decided to just abandon Sockets and instead use WebSockets. I managed to get a WebSocket server running. Thanks for your help though